# Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.[Angular 8]

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular8, ngfor

I'm trying to Get array data from the following API:
http://dradiobeats.x10host.com/api/areas

**API**

[image]

[image]

***My app.component.ts:***

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { User } from "./users.model";
import { UsersService } from "./users.service";

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  users$: User[];

  constructor(private userService: UsersService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    return this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(Data => (this.users$ = Data));
  }
}
```

***app.component.html:***

```html
<div *ngFor="let users of users$">
  <p>{{ users.name }}</p>
</div>
```

***user.service.ts:***

```html
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { User } from "./users.model";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class UsersService {
  apiUrl = "http://dradiobeats.x10host.com/api/areas";

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}

  getUsers() {
    return this._http.get<User[]>(this.apiUrl);
  }
}
```

***user.model.ts:***

```html
export class User {
  name: string;
  description: string;
  domain: string;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: your API is returning a  object and you are trying to iterate it . your incoming data looks something like this `{ data: [ ]  }` you will have to change code inside your `.subscribe` to  something like `this.users$ = Data['data']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API has returned an object containing your data, rather than an array.
If you console.log() (or look at the link you posted) the result of the API call you will see that it probably has another element inside that is an array e.g.

```
{
  data: [... list of items...]
}
```

So you just need to change the line of code to be:

```
return this.userService.getUsers().subscribe(Data => (this.users$ = Data.data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign `users$` an empty array like this:

```
users$: User[] = [];
```